# SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition Unable to Install SQL Server (setup.exe)

Tags: sql-server

I had an old version of SQL Server on my laptop which I uninstalled. Now I am trying to install SQL Server 2019 Developer edition but I get an error:

> Error Code(Decimal): 2068052293 Error Description: Please install the Visual C++2017 Redistributable from https://aka.ms/vs/15/releaset..exe before running this installer.

I also installed Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable from the suggested path but still same error is happening.

Environment: HP/Pavilion/Windows 10 Pro/4g/500HDD/Corei5

PS: attaching screenshot for kind reference

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2HyM.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Screenshot is missing.
2. Check for the following,

   - Is, VC++ 2017 is successfully installed? If yes, its worth doing a restart. Sometimes certain dll's should be registered in Windows environment, which will happen after a restart. Start SQL Server 2019 again after restarting.
   - Ensure both SQL Server 2019 and VC++ 2017 are installed with same user login. Hopefully you should be local admin for the login.

More suggestion can be provided based on screenshot error. Good luck!

Comment: In the Error description link was given to install VC ++ 2017 ( https://aka.ms/vs/15/releaset.exe) using this I installed VC++ 2017 successfully.

But still same same error is coming even after restart.

Comment: Please find the screenshot     https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2HyM.png

Comment: One more additional question. Did you checked for 64bit and 32bit compatibility? Say for example, SQL Server 2019 might be 32 bit, but VC++ 2017 might be 64 bit. Confirm both are same.

Comment: Sir, both are same. I am very much disturbed since last 2-days because of this issue. My study has hampered. I tried this issues with all my contacts on LinkedIn, Twitter but only you are responding.

If possible, kindly connect with zoom for a while and resolve my issues, for this I would be highly obliged to you.

With Regards,

Comment: Is any essential supporting software for SQL Server 2019 has deleted during the uninstallation of Old SQL Server. Thought?

Comment: I am not sure Rakesh. My only assumption is, improper VC++ 2017 setup. How can we fix this? Its very wide topic. I will explore and get back.

Comment: Below are latest error showing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y1KnPYXGOg_l8rkLVs4pSFThgNcFAsxa/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Unable to install sql server (setup.exe) error code (decimal):- 2147467259 Error description: the system cannot find the path specified

Comment: Does the log file shows any additional information Rakesh?

Answer (score 0):

This is my suggestion. It worked for me. Partition your local disk and install MSSQL in the new drive. That's all. Problem solved. This problem often happens with windows 11.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).